# Why is Pundit not coupled with Rolify like CanCanCan is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan, rolify, pundit

I am using Devise and interested in using Pundit but cannot find much on if it should be integrating with Rolify or if it is stand alone.  CanCanCan works nicely with Rolify and I like the roles model.  Am I missing a major reason why Pundit and Rolify do not seem to be used together a lot?

Comment: Pundit will work just fine with Rolify, or any other role system.

Comment: @sevenseacat this is also a correct answer

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Why don't use them together? They can be easily used in a fashion like this

```
class OrganisationPolicy
  def initialize(user, organisation)
    @user = user
    @organisation = organisation
  end

  def index?
    @user.has_role? :admin
  end

  def show?
    @user.has_role?(:admin) || @user.organisation == @organisation
  end
end
```

In fact, the thing that `rolify` and `pundit` are not coupled is something nice, and not a design failure ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recently used Pundit gem with Rails 4 using devise.Pundit is standalone system with no dependency on Rolify as per my experience.

Instead of using Rolify, I created migration to add roles in the existing devise user table which helps you  to assign roles to users and check which roles they have.

Please take a look at the schema that I created for my project:

```
 create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    **t.boolean  "is_admin"
    t.boolean  "is_daily_user"
```

Where `is_admin` and `is_daily_user` field is added for user roles.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will work, but it's not scalable. Imagine you wanted to add a is_premium user. You would have to change your DB model. Create instead your own model UserRole(:id, :role_name) that belongs_to user where you can create as many role names as you like per user... I went with Rolify gem, though ;)