# Rails Rolify with Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parentheses, pundit, rolify

The guidance in this post shows how to use [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) with pundit authorisations.

I'm trying to figure out how to this in my Rails app.

What's confusing me about the answer in the linked post is that the index action checks for `:admin`, where the show action checks for `(:admin)`. Is there a reason for the brackets in some cases?

[Why is Pundit not coupled with Rolify like CanCanCan is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172128/why-is-pundit-not-coupled-with-rolify-like-cancancan-is)

```
  def index?
    @user.has_role? :admin
  end

  def show?
    @user.has_role?(:admin) || @user.organisation == @organisation
  end
```

Comment: Do you mean parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby allows you to leave out parenthesis, it's more like a coding style.

Normally we omit parenthesis when it comes to methods that are with *keyword* status in *Ruby*. (`puts`, `attr_accessor` etc.) for the rest methods, we can use `()`

You can learn more on this here: [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean parentheses is because of the style guide that makes the `@user.has_role?(:admin) || @user.organisation == @organisation` more readable than `@user.has_role? :admin || @user.organisation == @organisation` there are multiple code style guides.